# C++ Nvidia Cg question

Tags: c++, shader, nvidia, cg

I started using `Nvidia Cg` shaders recently and everything looks and works fine if I'm doing it on the `Nvidia GPU` (`GTS250` in my case).

I tried launching the same (my own test application) on `ATI HD4650` and saw no output. Right after that I started experimenting with test examples (provided with `Nvidia Cg 3.0`) and 6/7 work, but the first one *(which seems to be the simpliest)* doesn't.

***Here is the shader code:***

```
// This is C2E1v_green from "The Cg Tutorial" (Addison-Wesley, ISBN
// 0321194969) by Randima Fernando and Mark J. Kilgard.  See page 38.

struct C2E1v_Output {
  float4 position : POSITION;
  float3 color    : COLOR;
};

C2E1v_Output C2E1v_green(float2 position : POSITION)
{ 
  C2E1v_Output OUT;

  OUT.position = float4(position,0,1);
  OUT.color = float3(0,1,0);

  return OUT; 
}
```

*I have no ideas why doesn't this simple shader work, while for example the same shader **paired** with the following passthru-shader does work (example 2 from the `Nvidia Cg SDK`):*

```
// This is C2E2f_passthru from "The Cg Tutorial" (Addison-Wesley, ISBN
// 0321194969) by Randima Fernando and Mark J. Kilgard.  See page 53.

struct C2E2f_Output {
  float4 color : COLOR;
};

C2E2f_Output C2E2f_passthru(float4 color : COLOR)
{
  C2E2f_Output OUT;
  OUT.color = color;
  return OUT;
}
```

***Did someone face the same troubles? Any ideas?***

Thank you.

---

**Update here:** Turning on maximum debug output made the problem obvious:

```
vs_3_0 shader executed in hardware vertex processing mode can only be paired
with at least a ps_3_0 shader
```

The first example in that package was the only one which had ONLY vertex shader in it, without any (even simple passthrough) pixel shader. I have no idea why does Nvidia Cg runtime generates incompatible shader in this case, but it obviously failed only on a somewhat old GPU (`ATI HD4650`).

*Anyway, I was stupid enough to work without turning the debug output on.*

**2 Alex Farber:** I guess you can post a dummy answer, so that I can award bounty to you, because you helped me realize that I forgot to turn debugging on. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see some trace messages, when Debug DirectX version is enabled in the DirectX Control Panel?

Comment: @Alex Nothing when everything works (`Nvidia GPU`) and tomorrow I'm gonna see if there are some with my `ATI GPU`.

Comment: Of course, it is interesting to see when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Debug DirectX version in the DirectX control panel and see trace output to get the reason of this failure.

BTW, I had the same situation with my pixel shader and got help in GameDev.net DirectX forum. I remember that finally I converted the shader to lowest version using SDK conversion tool, and it worked without pixel shader. According to GPU provider, this behavior is according to DirectX specification.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. I'll award the bounty when possible.